# Using brace expansion to create names, some of them must repeat once

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I would like to automatically create a list of URLs, using a command like this one:

```
echo www.somewebsite.com/{1,2,3}_{foo,bar}/{1,2,3}
```

But I **do not** want  all the links in the form

> www.somewebsite.com/1_foo/1
>   www.somewebsite.com/1_foo/2
>    ...

I only want those whose numbers match. That is, I want the first one, because both numbers match, but not the second one, because the numbers do not match.

Comment: Are you expecting the numbers to be the same (e.g. `{1,2,3}` in both places, or `{1,3}` in one place and `{3,5}` in the other).  I think you should better detail your expected output.  Are you expecting to have both the `foo` and the `bar` version for each matching number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `{1..3}` expansion to a separate loop:

```
for x in {1..3} ; do 
    echo www.somewebsite.com/${x}_{foo,bar}/${x}
done
```

If you need to use variables, use a `C` style loop:

```
i=1
j=3     
for ((x=i; x<=j; x++)); {
    echo www.somewebsite.com/${x}_{foo,bar}/${x} | tr ' ' '\n'
}
```

Either case:

```
www.somewebsite.com/1_foo/1 www.somewebsite.com/1_bar/1
www.somewebsite.com/2_foo/2 www.somewebsite.com/2_bar/2
www.somewebsite.com/3_foo/3 www.somewebsite.com/3_bar/3
```

If you want 1 per line, add `echo www.somewebsite.com/${x}_{foo,bar}/${x} | tr ' ' '\n'`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works better for you:

```
for num in `seq 1 3`
do
  printf "%s\n" www.somewebsite.com/${num}_{foo,bar}/${num}
done
```

Comment: Yeah, that should do it, although `{foo,bar}` is not working as intended

Comment: They are not expanding

Comment: plus one to @ffledgling's answer

Comment: You should replace `echo` with `printf "%s\n"` to avoid getting both expanded strings on the same line at each iteration.

Comment: @D1X they expand for me. What shell are you using? What's the output that you get?

Comment: @Fred, true, or one could add a `| tr ' ' '\n'` at the end of the `echo` to have each URL on it's own line. Replacing with a `printf` would force you to loop over `foo,bar` as instead of using the built-in expansion.

Comment: @ffledgling: No need to loop over `foo` and `bar`. Read what `printf` does when the number of attributes is higher than the number of format placeholders.

Comment: @choroba you're right. I tried it out and it works. TIL. Still trying to find out why, but I'll update the answer when I've gotten the right explanation.

Comment: @ffledgling You are right, they expand, I was executing the script with `sh`. I have just discovered that `sh` is not an alias for 0`bash` ...